# SQL query with SELECT,COUNT and subquery joins not returning rows

Tags: sql, oracle, select, count, subquery

I have the below select query that returns the following data:

query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ALLVW.GP_PAYGROUP,
                ALLVW.PRD_END_DT,
                TMP.PRD_END_DT
FROM PS_AZ_DFN_ALPRD_VW ALLVW,
     PS_AZ_DFMPRP_TMP4 TMP
WHERE ALLVW.GP_PAYGROUP = TMP.GP_PAYGROUP
  AND ALLVW.PRD_END_DT < TMP.PRD_END_DT
```

result:

```
PAYGROUP    PRD_END_DT      PRD_END_DT_1

AMZ_PG_T1   31-JAN-12   31-DEC-12
AMZ_PG_T1   29-FEB-12   31-DEC-12
AMZ_PG_T1   31-MAR-12   31-DEC-12
AMZ_PG_T1   30-NOV-12   31-DEC-12
AMZ_PG_T2   31-JAN-12   31-OCT-12
AMZ_PG_T2   30-SEP-12   31-OCT-12
AMZ_PG_T2   31-MAR-12   31-OCT-12
AMZ_PG_T2   30-APR-12   31-OCT-12
```

So now, I want the `PRD_END_DT` for each `PAYGROUP` that is 'x' number of periods prior to the `PRD_END_DT_1` for eg is x = 1, my query should return:

```
 PAYGROUP    PRD_END_DT      PRD_END_DT_1
 AMZ_PG_T1   30-NOV-12       31-DEC-12
 AMZ_PG_T2   30-SEP-12       31-OCT-12
```

I tired doing the below but no help all:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ALLVW.GP_PAYGROUP,
                ALLVW.PRD_END_DT,
                TMP.PRD_END_DT
FROM PS_AZ_DFN_ALPRD_VW ALLVW,
     PS_AZ_DFMPRP_TMP4 TMP
WHERE ALLVW.GP_PAYGROUP = TMP.GP_PAYGROUP
  AND ALLVW.PRD_END_DT < TMP.PRD_END_DT
  AND 1 =
    (SELECT COUNT(XVW.PRD_END_DT)
     FROM PS_AZ_DFN_ALPRD_VW XVW
     WHERE XVW.GP_PAYGROUP = TMP.GP_PAYGROUP
       AND XVW.PRD_END_DT < TMP.PRD_END_DT)
```

Could you suggest possible approaches please. Appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  your original SELECT DISTINCT... query
) t where datediff(month, PRD_END_DT, PRD_END_DT_1) = x
```

Comment: I am not specifically looking for months here. i am just looking for the prior period. The prior period date could also be in the previous week as opposed to month. Also edited my question now.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ALLVW.GP_PAYGROUP, ALLVW.PRD_END_DT, TMP.PRD_END_DT
FROM PS_AZ_DFN_ALPRD_VW ALLVW
JOIN PS_AZ_DFMPRP_TMP4 TMP ON ALLVW.GP_PAYGROUP = TMP.GP_PAYGROUP
WHERE ALLVW.PRD_END_DT < TMP.PRD_END_DT
  AND add_months(trunc(ALLVW.PRD_END_DT, 'month'), 1) >= trunc(TMP.PRD_END_DT, 'month')
```

Comment: I am not specifically looking for months here. i am just looking for the prior period. The prior period date could also be in the previous week as opposed to month. Also edited my question now.

Comment: @MikeG: modified answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked. But what if I dont just want the prior month per se and what if I want a prior week. Do i need to change the 'month' to 'week'. Is there a generic solution for this at all so that query would just get the period that is 'x' periods prior.

Comment: Basically - I am looking for max(prd_end_dt) where count(prd_end_dt) between the date = x

Comment: @MikeG: The difficulty is in calculating the beginning of the prior week (or any other period).  In many cases it's a semantic calculation, not subject to standard mathematical operators, and it requires using day/month/week recognition.  If you can say 'x days ago' that makes it much simpler, and you can make a generic formula for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try and use `dense_rank` function:

E.g.

```
Select a, b, c
From ( select a, b, c, dense_rank() over (partition by a order by b desc) r
       from table)
Where r < :x
```